# Product data update inconsistency

Tags: product, magento2.2, upgrade

when I am updating product using the following code

```
$product = $this->productFactory->create()->load($productId);
foreach ($attrData as $key => $value) {
    $product->setDataUsingMethod($key, $value);
} 

$product->setStockData(['qty' => $newqty, 'is_in_stock' => $newss]);
```

`$this->productFactory` is object of `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory`

the product updated data in product grid is not getting updated, only data in product edit section is getting updated. In the grid, I am getting older values even after the cache flush and re-indexation.

When I am saving data using the following method

```
$this->productAction->create()->updateAttributes([$productId], $attrData, $storeId);
```

`$this->productAction` is object of `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\ActionFactory`

everything works as expected and the data in product edit section and product grid is same.

Why is it like so and what is the reason for this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

The diffrence that I can see is for reindexing,

In `updateAttributes` method this indexer will reindex if you set `update on save` for reindexing

```
`catalog_product_attribute`
```

and for product save it will reindex `catalog_product_flat`

**Update**

I think problem is in below method in `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product.php`

Here Magento reset old data for that attribute so may be that's why you get old values

> I am not sure this is the exact issue or not but may be this is the issue

```
public function addAttributeUpdate($code, $value, $store)
{
    $oldValue = $this->getData($code);
    $oldStore = $this->getStoreId();

    $this->setData($code, $value);
    $this->setStoreId($store);
    $this->getResource()->saveAttribute($this, $code);

    $this->setData($code, $oldValue);
    $this->setStoreId($oldStore);
}
```

That is the only difference that I saw while saving both

Comment: yes you are correct but I am running the re-indexation via CLI after executing the code and still, the data is inconsistent.

Comment: @AnshuMishra please check update section and please try and let me know,as  I am not sure this is the issue or not

Comment: I have checked by updating the name, but I don't see this method being called in the process. Do you know how and when this method gets called?